# how to pass enum type value in method code given error Error: expecting right curly bracket, found 'enum'

Tags: unit-test

```
public enum FieldToSort {Label, Value}    
    public static void doSort(List<Selectoption> opts, FieldToSort sortField) {        
        Map<String, Selectoption> mapping = new Map<String, Selectoption>();        
        Integer suffix = 1;
        for (Selectoption opt : opts) {
            if (sortField == FieldToSort.Label) {
                mapping.put( (opt.getLabel() + suffix++), opt);   
            } else {
                mapping.put( (opt.getValue() + suffix++), opt);   
            }
        }        
        List<String> sortKeys = new List<String>();
        sortKeys.addAll(mapping.keySet());
        sortKeys.sort();        
        opts.clear();        
        for (String key : sortKeys) {
            opts.add(mapping.get(key));
        }
    }
```

This is test class

```
List<Selectoption> opts =new List<Selectoption>();
        opts.add(new Selectoption('abc','abc'));
        opts.add(new Selectoption('xyz','xyz'));
        enum FieldToSort {Label, Value};
        DiscoverOrg_clsBrowse.doSort(opts, FieldToSort.Label);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You need to pass enum value by below way

```
        List<Selectoption> opts =new List<Selectoption>();
        opts.add(new Selectoption('abc','abc'));
        opts.add(new Selectoption('xyz','xyz'));
        FieldToSort enumValue = FieldToSort.Label;
        DiscoverOrg_clsBrowse.doSort(opts, enumValue );
```

or

```
        List<Selectoption> opts =new List<Selectoption>();
        opts.add(new Selectoption('abc','abc'));
        opts.add(new Selectoption('xyz','xyz'));
        DiscoverOrg_clsBrowse.doSort(opts, FieldToSort.Label);
```

This works if you are executing this code in the class where enums are defined. Otherwise you need to consider creating a separate enum class.

```
public  enum FieldToSort {
    Label, 
    Value
}
```

This will make sure that it is publicly available and not scoped to the class in which it is defined.
Hope this helps you.